# How to implement trait with lifetime generically that implements trait

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime

How do I do the following?

```
trait Foo {}
trait Bar<'a> {}

impl<S> S for Bar<'_> where S: Foo {}
```

Comment: That syntax doesn't make sense in Rust. `S: Foo` means that `S` is a type. You can't say `impl SomeType for SomeTrait`.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for `impl<'a, S> Bar<'a> for S where S: Foo {}`? That's the same as `impl<S> Bar<'_> for S where S: Foo {}`, which you pretty much have in the question, only in reverse. Please describe in more detail what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @user4815162342 yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is indeed @user4815162342's answer:

```rs
impl<'a, S> Bar<'a> for S where S: Foo {}
```

You can also add default implementations to your trait:

```rs
trait Bar {
    pub fn hello() {
        println!("Hello, world!");
    }
}

struct Foo {}

impl Bar for Foo {}

// ...
Foo::hello();
```